# How to fix iTunes wrong song time?

Tags: itunes

My mp3 in iTunes shows a time of about 20 minutes, when it really have about 5 minutes. The VLC Player and the Windows Media Player shows the correct time for the same file, what's wrong with my iTunes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The incorrect time is most likely due to an error introduced by the encoding software. You can repair the problem by using the *Convert to AAC* feature in **iTunes**.

In **iTunes 11** this feature can be found under the *Create New Version →* option of the *File* menu.

Comment: This is apparently no longer a solution in iTunes 12.9.5.5.  My song was in MP3, but the file menu had no AAC conversion.  Only convert to MP3, which it did, making two MP3 files, both still with the wrong length.  Deleting them from the library, closing iTunes, renaming the file, then opening iTunes and re-importing gave it the same wrong length as before.

Comment: Worked for me in iTunes 12.12.3.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

[How can I fix incorrect mp3 duration @ askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248811/how-can-i-fix-incorrect-mp3-duration) had a couple of command line solutions.

For me, the ffmepg solution worked (ffmepg can be installed to OS X with Homebrew, for example):

```
ffmpeg -i file_orig.mp3 -acodec copy file_fixed.mp3
```

Comment: This even fixed files that were generated by `ffmpeg`!

Comment: this worked but holy moly `ffmpeg` has a ton of cask dependencies!

Comment: Much better than letting iTunes transcode to AAC.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Van Cool's fix did not work.  Jaberg's suggestion worked, but I found an easier way to get to the "Convert ..." option.  From the songs menu, right click on the songs with the bad time & "Convert to AAC" is in the popup menu.  Fixed 4 songs in under a minute, added the M4A files to my playist, and burning to CD worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong time duration, is not solved with iTunes 11 and it's not depending from the encoding software (with the new releases of iTunes).

Even re-loading the file, deleting it form the device, often doesn't sovle the problem.

the only one effective solution I found (I got several times this issue) is:

- Remove the file with iTunes form your device
- Check if the song was really removed from the device, into the device
  itself with iTunes on the iPhone or iPad. If not, touch the title,
  shift your finger to left, and a red rectangle "DELETE" will appear
  and touch it.
- Rename the file of the song and re-upload it.

The reason of the 3rd point above is that: I noticed that often, even applying the first 2 points, for some reason (unknown to me), the device still put the old duration and/or old parameters. Changing the original file name, solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My track was more than an hour, but it only showed 1h04mins. Converting to AAC or apple lossless didn't work for me.

Fixed it by using this app called Tag Stripper, https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tag-stripper/id432262744?mt=12

1. strip the track of its ID3 tags
2. import it fresh into iTunes. Track duration should be fixed now
3. cmd+i to edit the id3 tags.

Done.
There might be a simpler way, but this worked for me.

Comment: In my case it was a tag issue as well, and I was able to trace it down to the ITUNSMPB tag that iTunes uses for seamless playback. Removing just that one tag (Mp3Tag) and reimporting to iTunes solved the issue. I'm sure that tag is valid in many cases, but apparently not this one. (It had been included in a direct purchase from the author.) It might be worth trying to remove just that tag before wiping all of them.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is pull up my editing software and cut out the length that was having the problem, and created a new file. Nothing else worked for me.